# Automatically Highlight Specific Word in Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, highlight, content-script

In the content scripts of my chrome extension I am trying to inject code that highlights a specific word in the page.

In this instance, I am viewing espn.com and would like to have all instances of 'bryant' highlighted in the text immediately as the page is loaded.

This is the current code I have customized after viewing several questions similar to mine:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
highlight_words('Bryant', all);

function highlight_words(keywords, element) {
    if(keywords) {
        var textNodes;
        keywords = keywords.replace(/\W/g, '');
        var str = keywords.split(" ");
        $(str).each(function() {
            var term = this;
            var textNodes = $(element).contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType === 3 });
            textNodes.each(function() {
                var content = $(this).text();
                var regex = new RegExp(term, "gi");
                content = content.replace(regex, '<span class="highlight">' + term + '</span>');
                $(this).replaceWith(content);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

In my jquery-ui.css I have the following code.  I understand it does not highlight at this moment but I am just trying to get a proof of concept:

```
.highlight {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

At this time everything loads properly but no iteration of 'bryant' is read in bold.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do this is to define the what are you want to search for highlight, for example:

You have 3 parts on site, the navbar on left, the title on the top and the content.

Lets attach `.foo` class to article.

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("foo")
var search_word = ""
var contents = []

for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
var contents = list[i].textContext.split(search_word)
list[i].textContext = contents.join('<span class="heighlight\">'+search_word+'</span>')
}
```

Hope it will help.

(The highlight is bound to elements that have .foo class)

some example: https://jsfiddle.net/Danielduel/0842qntu/2/

Comment: I just executed

`var list = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
console.log(list);`

and it logs nothing...I'm guessing I do not fundamentally grasp what you mean.  Can you elaborate?  Thanks!

Comment: @Lance You have to have this element with some content, this is an array of elements in document that have the foo class. And you have to run this code after generation of document

Comment: I want this to be able to apply to any web page, which is why I attempted the * wildcard in my initial attempt.  How can I get it to auto iterate through any DOM, look at the text, and insert childnodes around certain text?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the JSFiddle.  However, in working in the content scripts, I need the highlighting to conform to any page; therefore I cannot have a predetermined name for class because every page may be different.  How do I have the class automatically pick up on whatever is in the page?

Comment: Load then document.body instead of specific element

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103514/discussion-between-lance-and-daniel-mizerski).